# How to get data from an occasionally connected device (laptop) to backend SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce, replication

I am writing a program for my work that would allow an employee to use a laptop in the field and sync what they have done back to the server once they return to the office.

I have completed this task with Windows Mobile 6.5 and RDA through Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5. My problem is that SQL Server CE 3.5 does not support geospatial datatypes which are needed.

Also newer versions of SQL Server CE do not support RDA (remote data access). In the past I have tried replication but found it to be overkill for the small projects I am working on.

Can I use SQL Server Express to sync back data to the database once the user returns to the network?? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 standard on the network.

Comment: SQL CE 4.0 DOES work with RDA, though

Comment: @ErikEJ do you have any resources that state that? I did a quick search and found it didnt. I could be wrong though

Comment: Either way, SQLCE doesnt support spatial datatypes

Comment: I found that the answer to many of my problems was to create a LINKED SERVER. Once I added the SqlExpress Instance to the network server as a linked server I was able to use a TSQL query to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SQL Server Express, as long as the database size doesn't get larger than the limit. That maximum, for SQL Server Express 2008 R2 is 10 GB. Further, I would recommend SQL Server Express over SQL Server CE any day.

I did an offline database project one time and we found that SQL Server Express was the right approach as well. It's a fully featured database.

Comment: how would I set up the Sql express. THere is going to be atleast 4 laptops that are going to use this. Would I have to create a SQL instance for each laptop?

Comment: @CodeSlinger, just install it on each of them. The `SERVER` for the connection string on each would be the same (if the default settings were used), and that would be `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Is there a way to do change tracking so one person doesnt over write the other onces they all get back to the office to sycn their changes? I know replication does this but I had a hard time with replication in the past.

Comment: @CodeSlinger, you're up against a wall on that. It's an extremely complex solution that is dependent on your domain. Synchronizing the data when you get back is at best, messy, and at worst, border-line impossible for some transactions. If you look at it as a **manual** process for those doing the synchronization then you'll be more successful. Manual meaning they resolve conflicts manually.

Comment: @CodeSlinger, we ended up using the `Timestamp` data type to manage determining what rows changed. So, if the `Timestamp` on the server didn't match the `Timestamp` on the client, we know that row is different, so it's conflict resolution time.

Comment: I had a really great solution until I started using spatial data types. I think Ill be able to get through the problems... thanks for the info man. Huge help

Comment: how did you end up getting the data back and forth from the local db to the network db??

Comment: @CodeSlinger, when the users connected to the network again, they issued a "Sync" inside the application. When this happened I compared all of the data in the database, leveraging the `Timestamp` column. I then made the users manage conflicts by hand with a custom interface I had to develop. If the conflicts could be handled automatically, I just performed them automatically.

Comment: Im actually asking "how" meaning how can you update a local database with data from a network server. Is there a query that will insert data from two instances on separate machines or do I have to go through a webservice or something

Comment: @CodeSlinger, as long as they are on the same network the local machine can read the data it wants from the network server and place it in the local database. However, if they are not on the same network, or permissions is an issue, then yes you'd need something like a web service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38910/discussion-between-codeslinger-and-neoistheone)